# Natural join vs Cartesian product with equality condition

Tags: relational-algebra

Which one is better in performance (memory and comparisons)?
Natural join or cartesian product with equality condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644807/performance-of-inner-join-vs-cartesian-product

Comment: Performance has no meaning for "relational algebra", it's just some operators with outputs that are a function of inputs. You have to specify how a particular implementation executes relational expressions if you want to compare how different expressions are executed. Please be more specific about the context you are asking this in. Please give a reference to what version of "relational algebra" you are tallking about. Read about logical & physical query optimization/implementation. PS Inner join is not normally cosidered a relational algebra operator, it is an SQL operator.